# como puedo eliminar elementos repetidos de una lista?

Tags: haskell

Si tengo esta lista

```
[a,b,c,d] y esta otra [a,b,c,a,c,b,d,a,d,c]
```

como puedo eliminar los elementos repetidos de esta lista `[a,b,c,a,c,b,d,a,d,c]` para que me quede asi `[a,b,c,d]`

Comment: @ChemaCortes en realidad es, si tengo esta lista `[a,b,c,d]` y esta otra `[a,d,a,c,d,c,c,a,a,b,b,d,a]` como puedo eliminar los elementos repetidos y que me quede como esta `[a,b,c,d]`

Comment: Buf! Ya veo que has cambiado tanto la pregunta que la respuesta que habías aceptado como correcta no se corresponde con el enunciado.

Comment: @ChemaCortes ajajajaj si

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
deleteN :: Int -> [a] -> [a]
deleteN _ []     = []
deleteN n (h:t)
  | n == 0    = t
  | otherwise = h : deleteN (n-1) t
```

Esta solución está bastante optimizada, es recursiva terminal y tan sólo recorre la lista una vez.

Para eliminar los elementos duplicados(Según la edición de la pregunta) puedes usar la función `nub`,del módulo `Data.List`, de esta manera `nub lista`.
Para no usar librerías(Indicado en comentario), se puede consultar el source:

```
nub                     :: (Eq a) => [a] -> [a]
nub l                   = nub' l []
  where
    nub' [] _           = []
    nub' (x:xs) ls
        | x `elem` ls   = nub' xs ls
        | otherwise     = x : nub' xs (x:ls)
```

Comment: cuales serian los parámetros

Comment: edito la pregunta?

Comment: @Efrainrodc ¿Qué quieres añadir?

Comment: no nada, si me pudieras ayudar en la otra pregunta que hice te lo agradecería 2 @DavidMasedaNeira

Comment: No entiendo cual es la otra pregunta. He leido los otros comentarios pero no me ha quedado claro.

Comment: ya la edite @DavidMasedaNeira

Comment: me parece bien pero mano no puedo usar librerías :/ hay alguna forma de ver el código de la función nub? @DavidMasedaNeira

Comment: Editada la respuesta. Por favor, trata de dejar claro todas las condiciones en la pregunta inicial.